# Can someone please explain how to use Kibana dashboards from a .Net web application without viewing other users' data?

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-shield

In an forthcoming web application, we will be using ElasticSearch as the repo for our .Net-based web application.

I would like to be able to create a set of dashboards in Kibana that will reflect each user's specific data.  That is, a logged in user will see their own data reflected in the Kibana dashboard.  I would also like to allow users to create their own dashboards through Kibana as well.

I have read about [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) and [user roles in the Kibana documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/kibana.html#kibana4-user-role), but I am unclear as to whether or not this is necessary.

In terms of our proposed architecture, the Kibana and ES server are blocked from the outside world, only accessible by web server requests (.Net application).  User authentication has already been done through the .Net application, and request filtering implemented in a way that the logged-in userID is appended to all data queries.

Is it possible to send filtered (parameterized) requests for data to Kibana, and is it possible to accomplish this, if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your question and Shield. If you don't want to use Shield and you have your own implementation of authentication, it's fine. Kibana doesn't require Shield usage.

Comment: I want to allow authenticated users to be able to run/create their own dashboards and not see other users' data.

Comment: Right, and still: what does that have to do with Shield?

Comment: Maybe if you can clarify what it doesn't have to do with shield, please, as I thought Shield enables user and role-based authentication on RESTful verb execution.  I will reword the question, but if you could please clarify on Shield.

Comment: `User authentication has already been done through the .Net application, and request filtering implemented in a way that the logged-in userID is appended to all data queries.` this implies you have your own authentication mechanism. That's the reason for my question. If it's something else that you need, maybe you need to re-read your question and reformulate.

Comment: OK...I reworded the question.  Does that make more sense now?